# Template or render function not defined in vue-youtube-embed

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using this plugin for vue
https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-youtube-embed
But when I use it . It gives me this error . I don't know what is causing this error

```
Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not 
defined.
```

Here is my source code

```
        <template>
        <div>
            <youtube :video-id="'wyNGaq8XmH8'"></youtube>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        import VueYouTubeEmbed from  'vue-youtube-embed'
        Vue.component('youtube',VueYouTubeEmbed)
        export default {
            props:['progamData'],
            data(){
                return{
                    programs:[],
                    currentVideo:null,
                    player:null
                }
            }

        }
    </script>
```

Any help will be appriciated thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [vue-youtube-embed](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-youtube-embed) library is designed as a plugin. The line,

```
import VueYouTubeEmbed from  'vue-youtube-embed'
```

imports the *plugin*, not a component. If you want to import it locally to a component, you need to do it this way:

```
import VueYouTubeEmbed, {YouTubePlayer} from "vue-youtube-embed";
import Vue from "vue"

Vue.use(VueYouTubeEmbed, {global: false})

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    youtube: YouTubePlayer
  }
};
```

Here is a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/3r15rvxn61).

Alternatively, you could just use the plugin in your main script.

```
import VueYouTubeEmbed from "vue-youtube-embed";
Vue.use(VueYouTubeEmbed);
```

And here is a [working version](https://codesandbox.io/s/3yv1wy1m45) of that.